# Prove that a sequence is a Cauchy sequence iff the following holds

Tags: real-analysis

Show that a sequence $(x_n)$ in metric space $(S, \rho)$ is Cauchy if and only if $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{k \ge n} \rho(x_n,x_k)=0$

John Stachurski, Economic Dynamics, Exercise 3.2.1

Comment: Read the definition of Cauchy sequences; you'll find that the definition and the result you want to establish are equivalent.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I have reproduced what I have tried below in an answer. Let me know how I can shorten it more.

Answer (score 0):

Henno Brandsma, I have tried the following but I could not be more succint. Let me know how I can shorten it:

Let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence. Then, by definition, for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\rho(x_j,x_k)<\epsilon$ whenever $j\ge N$ and $k\ge N$

We know that: $$\sup_{k\ge n}\rho(x_n,x_k)\ge \sup_{k\ge n+1}\rho(x_n,x_k)\ge \sup_{k\ge n+2}\rho(x_n,x_k)\ge \ldots$$

We have to show that as $n\to \infty $ the above expression converges to zero. Suppose it converges to a $\delta>0$. Then, for all $\epsilon<\delta$, there does not exist an $N\in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\rho(x_j,x_k)<\epsilon$ whenever $j\ge N$ and $k\ge N$. This is a contradiction to our assumption of $(x_n)$ being a Cauchy Sequence.

---

Conversely, fix an $\epsilon>0$.

Then we can find an $N \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\sup_{k\ge n}\rho(x_n,x_k)<\epsilon\ \forall\ n\ge N$.

This implies that for such an $N$, $$\rho(x_n,x_k)\le \sup_{k\ge n}\rho(x_n,x_k)<\epsilon$$

This means that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy.

Comment: You rightly note the sequence of suprema is decreasing (and positive) so converges to some $\delta \ge 0$. Assume $\delta > 0$. Just take $\epsilon = \frac{\delta}{2}$, and apply Cauchyness. Then all (for sufficiently large $n,m$) $\rho(x_n, x_m)$ terms are bounded above by $\frac{\delta}{2}$ and so is their supremum. Contradiction. The other side is fine.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks!:)